# How can convert this C# code to C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli

How can I convert this segment of C# code to C++/CLI:

```
protected string GetMD5HashFromFile(string fileName)
{
  FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
  MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
  byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(file);
  file.Close();
  ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
  return enc.GetString(retVal);
}
```

Specially this part `byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(file);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Making liberal use of the stack semantics available in C++/CLI to automatically dispose objects.  An emulation of the Holy C++ RAII pattern, the object gets disposed even when the code throws an exception.  Think of it as the compiler automatically generating the C# *using* statement.  Look like this:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Security::Cryptography;
using namespace System::Text;

ref class Example {
protected:
    String^ GetMD5HashFromFile(String^ fileName)
    {      
        FileStream file(fileName, FileMode::Open);
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5;
        array<Byte>^ retVal = md5.ComputeHash(%file);
        return Convert::ToBase64String(retVal);
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks Hans Passant,, I would to ask you about `%` in `md5.ComputeHash(%file);` what is for?

Comment: ComputeHash requires a Stream^, file doesn't have a hat.  The % operator generates the reference.

Comment: :Ahaa, If I use  `FileStream^` I don't have to use `%file` right?

Comment: Well, yeah, but then it would be have the same bug your C# code has.  With the file not getting closed on an exception.

Comment: The function was compiled without errors but it returns a string like `???~???~O3??HafH` not hex MD5!

Comment: ASCII != hex, in C# as well.  You get the ? for any byte value >= 128.  Store bytes in a string with Convert::ToBase64String().

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of using the crypto service provider from C++ to generate an MD5 in the top answer to this question:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/c0f97655-d953-4e3f-82b9-b70edaf1625b/