# Conversion between Base64String and Hexadecimal

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, hex

I use in my C++/CLI project `ToBase64String` to give a string like `/MnwRx7kRZEQBxLZEkXndA==` I want to convert this string to Hexadecimal representation, How I can do that in C++/CLI or C#?

Comment: It seems quite stupid to convert to Base64 and then Hex a string. You could Hex directly the source. Unless you have other problems...

Comment: unless all you have is the base64 string ... maybe he doesn't have the source.  If so, then I agree.

Comment: Specifically, in Hans's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774648/how-can-convert-this-c-sharp-code-to-c-cli/7774720#7774720), get rid of `ToBase64String` and use `BitConverter::ToString` instead.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) will take the `string` to `byte`s

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(string s);
```

Then, `BitConverter.ToString()` will convert a byte array to a hex string ( [byte[] to hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623104/c-sharp-byte-to-hex-string) )

```
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to a byte array and then do a [byte to hex conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623104/c-sharp-byte-to-hex-string)

```
string stringToConvert = "/MnwRx7kRZEQBxLZEkXndA==";

byte[] convertedByte = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(stringToConvert);

string hex = BitConverter.ToString(convertedByte);

Console.WriteLine(hex);
```

Comment: I think the unicode.getbytes will treat that string as unicode chars when what you want is for the conversion to treat them as Base64.  I think Convert.FromBase64String() does exactly that ...

Answer (score 0):

```
public string Base64ToHex(string strInput)
{
    try
    {
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(strInput);
        var hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
        return hex.Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "-1";
    }
}
```

On the contrary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61224761/3988122

Comment: hex.Replace("-", "").ToLower();   This line is so important