# JavaScript CryptoJS.enc.Base64 equivalent C#

Tags: javascript, c#, base64, cryptojs

I am trying to convert JavaScript CryptoJS.enc.Base64 equivalent C#.
My staring string is "mickeymouse".
The toMD5  JavaScript code produces matched the C# code with the result of:
**98df1b3e0103f57a9817d675071504ba**

However, the toB64 code results in two different results for JavaScript vs C#.

JavaScript toB64 RESULT:  **mN8bPgED9XqYF9Z1BxUEug==**

C# toB64 RESULT:  **OThkZjFiM2UwMTAzZjU3YTk4MTdkNjc1MDcxNTA0YmE==**

What is the JavaScript CryptoJS.enc.Base64 equivalent C# so I can get the same results in C#?

```
            // Javascript
            // var toMD5 = CryptoJS.MD5("mickeymouse");
            // toMD5 RESULT: 98df1b3e0103f57a9817d675071504ba

            // C# (match with js)
            var toMD5 = CreateMD5("mickeymouse");
            // toMD5 RESULT: 98df1b3e0103f57a9817d675071504ba


            // Javascript
            // var toB64 = toMD5.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
            // toB64 RESULT:  mN8bPgED9XqYF9Z1BxUEug==

            // C# (not matched with js)
            var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toMD5);
            var toB64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
            // toB64 RESULT:  OThkZjFiM2UwMTAzZjU3YTk4MTdkNjc1MDcxNTA0YmE=
```

Comment: In C#, you seem to be base64-encoding an already hex-encoded string. If that's what your `CreateMD5` function returns and you can't change it, then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327156/convert-a-hex-string-to-base64 to first un-hex-encode the MD5 result and then base64-encode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your `CreateMD5` function does, but calculating MD5 bytes and passing them directly to `Convert.ToBase64String` produces expected result:

```cs
using var md5 = MD5.Create();
var hash = md5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("mickeymouse"));
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(hash) == "mN8bPgED9XqYF9Z1BxUEug==");// prints True
```

If you still need to use `CreateMD5` - use reverse algorithm to what was used to turn bytes into string, not just `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` (cause `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hash)` produces different result compared to `CreateMD5`)